# Split the unique values into the column

Tags: google-sheets, flatten

I want to split (text to column) every row by only the unique values.

I have tried using Flatten but not automatically generate the other rows.

could you give one-apply formula that can generate each row in it?
every help is appreciated.

Here is the document:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OJPswTTw-Bm4OHgtre8nrLG2H35uQeBg0nGHHeV124k/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you...

Comment: Are you looking for a *single* formula which auto-applies to all rows with data OR something else altogether?!

Comment: yes one single formula auto-applies to all rows. i think using arrayformula but doesnt work. @rockinfreakshow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;unique(split(Σ;",");1))))
```